# Fusion chart not printing in the print

Tags: printing, fusioncharts

i have a fusion chart and i want to print it but in the place of chart i am getting blank space.

Here is the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectBehaviourTypes(id){  
$.post('/reports/tbchart', {Guid: id, Chart:"yes"}, function(response)
{
    $("#chart_div").html(response);
});
}
</script>
<div style="float: right"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="printPage('pnlMainHeader','div_print');"><img src="<?=$this->baseUrl('/images/icons/small/print.png')?>" title="Print" alt="Print" /></a></div>  
<div id="div_print">
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Help me out
regards
uday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charts rendered are displayed properly on screen but printed output had been not proper try using PrintManager class for printing.

Print Manager takes a bit of time to prepare all the charts ready for printing.If print action is invoked while the Print Manager is not yet ready with the image, the chart does not show up in the print media. The function managedPrint() is called, it automatically waits for the chart to get ready before it proceeds to call the window.print() function.

For more information, please refer to : [FusionCharts  Print Manager Documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/JavaScript/JS_PrintManager.html)